# canonical form of (M B) (M B)

Tags: lambda-calculus

Are there lambda terms M and B with M =/= B, so that M B and (M B) (M B) have the same canonical form?

Is a problem I encountered while I am still new with lambda calculus
I approached this 
by having M = λx.x and B = λy.y
Μ Β = (λx.x) (λy.y) ->(β) λy.y

(M B) (M B) = ((λx.x) (λy.y)) ((λx.x) (λy.y)) ->(β)   (λy.y) ((λx.x) (λy.y)) ->(β) (λx.x) (λy.y) ->(β) λy.y
and thus getting the same canonical form, but I am not confident that I am correct about (M B) (M B).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming and should go on https://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The reductions you have posted are correct.

One thing to know is that you can use any name for the bound variable in a lambda term, so the terms `\x.x` and `\y.y` are not really different; they are the same term. This is called alpha equivalence.

Another thing to know is that the function `\x.x` that just returns its argument is called the identity function, and is very useful to know.

Here is an answer to your question where M and B are different. M can be a function that ignores its argument and returns the identity function: `\x.\y.y`. B can be any term different from M.
Then,
`(M B)` -> `\y.y` 
And also 
`((M B) (M B))` -> `(\y.y \y.y)` -> `\y.y`